# How to perform set difference between a data stream and a list (exclusion list) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a data stream in a loop. This retrieved results row by row from the database. However, I want to person a form of array-diff between the stream and a given array. The given array is an exclusion list say list of blacklisted users. So this is what I have so far.

This is a fictitious example. I don't want to write all the database codes retrieving results in row by row basis

```
database objects containing ("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");  //assume that this is a continous stream of data from a database where we don't know the total elements. Just that single element
$toys=array("BMW","Toyota");          //assume that this is a list of blacklisted users
for($rindex=0; $rindex < count($cars); $rindex++)
{

    for($index=0; $index < size(database objects); $index++)
    {
        //obtain the database object on a row by row basis
        if (strcmp ( $cars[$rindex] , $toys[$index] )!=0)  //specify exclusion
        {
        echo $cars[$rindex];

    }
    }
}
```

The expected answer should be `Volvo`. This could be done easily if we know all the element in `$cars` so we can't use `array-diff($cars,$toys)`. Assume that `$cars` is a continuous stream say a database result on a row by row basis. How could we do `array-diff()` between a fixed known blacklisted array and a continuous stream of data

Remember `array-diff()` cannot be used as we do not know the full size of the data stream or all the the element in the stream as we begin.

This can be done using `array-filter()` but I already have performance issues and want to do this operation online.

Kindly provide answers in PHP.

Comment: 1. `in_array` 2. `foreach` "where we don't know the total elements" -- and then you're using `count($cars)`? :-D

Comment: Q: This is homework, correct?  Q: Are either/both of the inputs sorted?  Q: Are you permitted to use [PHP in_array()](http://us1.php.net/in_array)?

Comment: This is not homework. I am new to PHP and trying to complete a part of a project.

Comment: Also check [`array_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and maybe [`array_intersect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Comment: How do you perform an exclusion on a database stream when retrieving the result on a row by row basis.

Comment: I don't know the size of the object the object are coming from a database on a row by row basis

Comment: I will edit the question to prevent confusion

Comment: Why not perform the filtering in your DB query?

Comment: I don't want to take another loop to filter the database because there is already some performance lag

Comment: I want to perform the set difference online with having to hit the database once more. I have been stuck on this problem for a while.

Comment: This is a big data related project where any database hit considerably slow the application. I have had lot of optimization to do but want to avoid more database hit.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what sort of database are you using? A real-time database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookup arrays quickly - the code is commented and tested. PHP 5.3.18

```
<?php // Q22754093

// database objects containing ("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");  //assume that this is a continous stream of data from a database where we don't know the total elements. Just that single element
$allToys = array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");


// use the 'toy' as the array key -- there is no faster way of checking whether
// something is in an array, especially if the array is large.
$badToys = array("BMW"     => true,
                 "Toyota"  => true);          //assume that this is a list of blacklisted users
                                              // by setting them false then you treat them as
                                             // 'good' if you wish - whatever


$checkedGoodToys = array();
$checkedBadToys  = array();

//obtain the database object on a row by row basis
foreach($allToys as $oneToy)
{
   if (isBadToy($oneToy)) {
       // do what you want with the bad toy...
       $checkedBadToys[] = $oneToy;
   }
   else {
       // do what you want with the good toy...
       $checkedGoodToys[] = $oneToy;
   }
}

var_dump($checkedGoodToys, 'The Good Toys');
var_dump($checkedBadToys,  'The Bad Toys');
exit;

// check if the toy is in the badToy array
function isBadToy($theToy)
{
    global $badToys;

    return isset($badToys[$theToy]) && $badToys[$theToy];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in_array() did the trick. Thanks for all your answers.

```
database objects containing ("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");  //assume that this is a continous  stream of data from a database where we don't know the total elements. Just that single element
$toys=array("BMW","Toyota");          //assume that this is a list of blacklisted users
for($rindex=0; $rindex < count($cars); $rindex++)
{

    for($index=0; $index < size(database objects); $index++)
    {
        //obtain the database object on a row by row basis
        if (in_array($cars[$rindex] , $toys)  //specify exclusion
        {
           echo $cars[$rindex];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be very slow on large arrays as on average half the array will have to be checked. Checking whether a key (index) exists is very quick and linear for large arrays. Basically, the cost is the hash calculation then the seek into the hash list which is normally one lookup in memory.